# Working with sequential workflow in CircleCI

Tags: python, continuous-integration, circleci

With the help of Real Python, I've learned about continuous integration through CircleCI. I wrote this `config.yml` file based off of the RP Tutorial:

```
version: 2
jobs:
  build:
    docker:
      - image: circleci/python:3.8

    working_directory: ~/repo

    steps:
      # Step 1: obtain repo from GitHub
      - checkout
      # Step 2: create virtual env and install dependencies
      - run:
          name: install dependencies
          command: |
            python3 -m venv venv
            . venv/bin/activate
            pip install -r requirements.txt
      # Step 3: run linter and tests
      - run:
          name: run tests
          command: |
            . venv/bin/activate
            pytest -v --cov
```

Next, after implementing the above in my current project and ensuring that it works, I went ahead and had a read through of the docs and found some other ways to write config files. Namely I liked the [sequential workflow format](https://circleci.com/docs/2.0/sample-config/#sequential-workflow), as it separates out building and testing as two different jobs. I tried to restructure the above config to follow this guideline:

```
# Python CircleCI 2.0 configuration file
version: 2
jobs:
  build:
    docker:
      - image: circleci/python:3.8

    working_directory: ~/repo

    steps:
      # Step 1: obtain repo from GitHub
      - checkout
      # Step 2: create virtual env and install dependencies
      - run:
          name: install dependencies
          command: |
            python3 -m venv venv
            . venv/bin/activate
            pip install -r requirements.txt
  unittest:
    docker:
      - image: circleci/python:3.8
      # Step 3: run linter and tests
    steps :
      - checkout
      - run:
          name: run tests
          command: |
            . venv/bin/activate
            pytest -v --cov
workflows:
  build_and_test:
    jobs:
      - build
      - unittest:
          requires:
            -build
```

However, this fails 0.3 seconds into the build with the error:

```
#!/bin/sh -eo pipefail
# Unsupported or missing workflows config version
# 
# -------
# Warning: This configuration was auto-generated to show you the message above.
# Don't rerun this job. Rerunning will have no effect.
false

Exited with code exit status 1
```

I would like to know what I have messed up. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

I got the same error and solved it by only changing version to be 2.1:
version: 2.1

Answer (score 0):

Alright, I figured out the issue:

In the Real Python tutorial both the building and testing was done in a single job, which was run inside of a single docker container.

What I didn't realize is that every job needs a docker, and that jobs don't share dockers.

That means in order to separate out my `build` and `test` jobs I have to:

1. recreate the virtual environment
2. reactivate it
3. reinstall install dependencies.

for both jobs. Only then can I run pytest.

This seems pretty inefficient, but it works now!

Answer (score 0):

I got the same and i fixed added version to workflow tab.
Like that:

```
workflows:
  version: 2
  build_and_test:
    jobs:
      ...
```

But careful spaces or tabs.